# Question about Installing Windows 7 - Unspported Device requires a Driver Disk

Tags: windows-7, installation, drivers, windows-pe

In a Windows 7 DVD I see two big files: boot.wim and install.wim. My assumption is that I can modify boot.wim  to affect the Windows Preinstallation Environment *itself*. Is this assumption correct?

To put it another way... Instead of providing a driver disk; Can I inject, using DISM, into `boot.wim`, using `dism /add-driver` ? Is this enough to enable support for a unsupported hard disk controller **within the installation environment itself**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You're also going to want to add it to install.wim as well, so that it gets installed, otherwise your system likely won't boot after.